# Adaptive mesh in FreeFem++

Tags: mesh, freefem++

I'm trying to improve my FreeFem++ code by adapting my initial mesh at certain time steps but FreeFem++ comes up with this error message:

```
Exec error : Try to get unset x,y, ...
```

after the mesh is indeed adapted. The problems seems to appear when computing the solution in the new mesh, but I haven't had this problem in other cases though. This is how I adapt the mesh in FreeFem++ and update the variables:

```
Th = adaptmesh(Th,[u1,u2]);
plot(Th);
u1 = u1;
u2 = u2;
p  = p;
```

but now I'm confused on how to proceed after the warning message.

Does anybody know how to solve this? Any piece of advice will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing? :( I promise to start a bounty.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a very old question, but my following answer is for those who still want to.

I ran into the same error when trying to output (`cout`) a FE variable `uh`, it's solved if we try `uh[]` instead. In this case, it's an array.

```
Vh uh = x;
cout << uh << endl; // error
cout << uh[] << endl; // good
```

Hope you can check the same thing for your problem.